# Multiple settings files

Tags: django, settings

I am trying to apply multiple settings files to my project. I am following basic two articles:

1 http://www.rdegges.com/the-perfect-django-settings-file/

2 Two scoops of Django: Best practices for Django 1.5
https://github.com/twoscoops/django-twoscoops-project

I have two questions:

1) I understand that it is important to have such files like secret key and aws keys out of settings. And in pydanny example on github I found this

```
SECRET_KEY = r"{{ secret_key }}"
```

I used this on my local and it pass even with no secret key on my environment variables (bashrc, profiles or virtualenvs).

How this SECRET_KEY = r"{{ secret_key }}" works?

2) After I created my settings folder. Also created the **init**.py and my base, local, stagging and production settings files. I notice that some subcommands disappear like collectstatic for example. I have to change my manage.py to local or base to start seeing them again.

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myproject.settings.local")
```

Why this works for base and local settings, but not for production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django's SECRET_KEY has many usages revolving around [cryptographic signing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/signing/). For example, this is how cookies are protected or how Django makes sure hidden form fields are not tampered with.

`manage.py runserver` is the development server that you should **not** use in production: you're probably using WSGI there: modifying manage.py won't do anything.

Comment: thanks... I thought r"{{ secret_key }}" called something... my bad.

Comment: @user227719 :) It's a raw string where, for example, "\n" really means "\" and "n", not "newline".